# Screen distorted when installing Ubuntu Mate 20.04.1

Tags: boot, system-installation, screen, ubuntu-mate

I want to move from Ubunut to Ubuntu MATE because my laptop is getting old. Booting from a USB though the screen is badly distorted, similar but not the same as [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/ag4i0m/screen_distortions_when_install_ubuntu_180401/). It is unreadable. I can blindly get past the first screen and either install or try it, but install leads me to network choice which I can't navigate blindly, and trying gives the normal desktop but still so badly distorted that I can't get to the settings or terminal.

Some threads suggest that `nomodeset` or changing grub might work, but how do  do that?

Comment: Is your installation readable if you select the *safe graphics* option?

Comment: How can I select the safe graphics option?

Comment: You can select it at the grub menu, however the same thumb-drive will look different on various boxes because of uEFI/BIOS/firmware settings/configuration on the box; but refer to https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/ubuntu-beginners-guide-complete-how-to-install-and-run-first-update/955  which specifically mentions "nomodeset".  It'll appear as "*Ubuntu MATE (safe graphics)*" on some boxes  Jump to the "*Okay, I've changed the boot order but I don't know what to do next*" section of that page.

Comment: Thanks! I've posted the answer of to the steps to take after, in case someone else needs them.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you Guiverc! The trick is in your link, which says to `

> press “any key” as soon as you see this symbol

Once in safe graphics mode I can use [this answer from Livipero](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/20-04-display-issues-with-amd-gpu/21648/3) Reposting in case someone else has the same issue and stumbles on this post.

> Boot live ISO, select safe graphics. Complete installation and shut down.
> On first boot, Hit "Esc" key to show GRUB menu, then "e" to edit, insert nomodeset at the end of the line that starts with "linux /boot/vmlinuz...". Press F10 to boot.
> Login and open "MATE Tweak".
> Select the third item from left panel: "Windows".
> In the Window Manager , switch to "Marco (No compositor)".
> Reboot (nomodeset will not be persistent so next boot is normal graphics mode).
> Enjoy.